# How to add event listener to dynamic div element that runs at server in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm adding some divs that each div of them supposed to redirect me to other page but with different parameters.

So, I started with this to get the values that according to them I add the div's :

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    CreateTableNameDiv("table", reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
}//On_Load


private void CreateTableNameDiv(string divClass, string tableName)
{
    HtmlGenericControl tableDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");//define a div
    HtmlGenericControl headerTableName = new HtmlGenericControl("h2");//define header inside the div
    headerTableName.InnerHtml = tableName;
    tableDiv.Attributes.Add("class", divClass);
    tableDiv.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    tableDiv.Controls.Add(headerTableName);
    tablesDiv.Controls.Add(tableDiv);
}
```

I need each div of this gets something like this onclick="Redirect_To"

```
private void Redirect_To(string tableName)
{
    Response.Redirect("TableEditor.aspx?val1=" + tableName);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Because adding `runat=server` as an attribute will not make it a "real" control. If you are binding data from a DB in a `while` loop, you might want to look into a GridView or Repeater Control.

Comment: And if the only thing you do in `Redirect_To` is a Redirect, why not make it a normal html link?

Comment: @VDWWD can I do something like this ? <a href="table.aspx?table=tb1">

Comment: Yes you can. It saves you a PostBack.

Comment: let me try, one second.

Comment: It was easier than what I think, nice one and thank you.